# Destructor of a future in async C++11

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

Should not a compiler call the destructor of the future `future` right after the `main` finishes, that is, should not be the function `f()` called anyway? (gcc 4.7.2 doesn't do that).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

void f() {
    cout << "thread...\n";
}

int main() {
    auto future = async(&f);
    cout << "I am main\n";
}
```

**edit**: I get **only** `Hello from main`. The text `thread...` is NOT printed at all.

**edit 2**: Does the destructor of a future call `wait()`??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Attention: outdated information (pre-C++14) below.** See Jonas’ answer for up-to-date information.

---

> Should not a compiler call the destructor of the future future right after the main finishes

Right *before* `main` finishes. But yes.

> that is, should not be the function f() called anyway?

No, why? What makes you think that the destructor of `std::future` would do that? This isn’t the destructor’s job. In fact, according to §30.6.6/9, the only function of the destructor is to release the shared state of the future and destroy `*this`. Nothing more.

Comment: On my machine `thread...` is not printed (Ubuntu 12.10, gcc 4.7.2).

Comment: @Martin Yes. Why do you expect it to be printed?

Comment: Oh, that means, that the function `f` needs not to be invoked, right?

Comment: @Martin: Yes. This will only happen if you actually wait for the function with either `std::future::wait` or `std::future::get` (although the latter simply calls the first). See http://ideone.com/22Itke

Comment: IIRC, isn't it being changed so that the destructor of a future calls `wait()`? I'm searching for now, but I think this is the case...

Comment: @GManNickG, It's true that a change was made in C++14 that changed the behavior, but not quite by merely calling `wait()` in the destructor. I added an answer to clarify these things with the benefit of hindsight.

Answer (score 2):

*This is the future speaking (pun intended):*

FWIW, Konrad's answer only holds true for C++11. In C++14, this behavior got changed. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/%7Efuture):

> these actions will not block for the shared state to become ready,
>   except that it may block if all of the following are true: the shared
>   state was created by a call to std::async, the shared state is not yet
>   ready, and this was the last reference to the shared state.

Even though the above quote does not mention the launch policy, I could only confirm this behavior in the case where the task is launched asynchronously. Futures created from `std::async(std::launch::deferred, ...)` which are never explicitly waited on don't seem to get evaluated upon destruction of the future, according to my testing.

Also note that this only pertains to futures created from `std::async`, so it is very much not the case that an additional `wait();` got slapped onto the destructor of `std::future`.

Lastly, as of Boost 1.73, the analogous change was **not** made for `boost::future`, when created by `boost::async(boost::launch::async, ...)`, i.e. the Boost version still behaves like `std::future` did pre-C++14.

Comment: When I try the following test under C++14 the future destructor still seems to block, https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67ad2d972ec97377.  Your answer implies you tested and saw it not block?